# Creating a custom options widget in web2py

Tags: python, widget, web2py

In web2py, built-in SQLFORM.widgets.options.widget gets options from Field's IS_IN_SET or IS_IN_DB requirements. I need a custom widget but I could not find any attribute or method of Field class to access the option set. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `IS_IN_SET` and `IS_IN_DB` validators via the field's "requires" attribute, and each of those validators has an `options()` method you can call to get a list of tuples with the options. For example:

```
>>> db.mytable.myfield.requires = IS_IN_SET(['apple', 'banana', 'orange'])
>>> print db.mytable.myfield.requires.options()
[('', ''), ('apple', 'apple'), ('banana', 'banana'), ('orange', 'orange')]
```